# PHP Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php

I'm struggling with my php script, i used this as my reference: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?60691-Listing-file-in-a-directory-problem.

I have adapted it to suit me a bit better, however i can't seem to work out how to fix this PHP Error:

> PHP Warning:  sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

I understand the error is on line 83

> sort($dirArray);

However i'm not sure how to fix the error, because i want that forbidden     files function to stay where it is, if i alter this:

```
  // Gets each entry
  while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
  {
    if (is_file($entryName))
    {
      $extensions = explode(".", $entryName);
        if(!in_array($extensions[1],$forbiddenExtensions))
        {
              $dirArray[] = $entryName;
        }
    }
  }
```

To this:

```
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) 
{
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}
```

I know it will be fine. I'm 100% positive theirs a simple solution, my brains just that fried I can't think anymore after 156 trials of re-editing, re-uploading, I'm in need of help. Can someone please help me find a workaround with my $forbiddenExtensions?

```
<?php
  // Open this directory
  // (NOTE: To open same folder as this file use($directory = "./";)
  $directory = "./files/";

  // Selects $directory to open
  $myDirectory = opendir($directory);

  // Sets forbidden extensions
  $forbiddenExtensions = array("php", "html", "log");

  // Gets each entry
  while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
  {
    if (is_file($entryName))
    {
      $extensions = explode(".", $entryName);
        if(!in_array($extensions[1],$forbiddenExtensions))
        {
          $dirArray[] = $entryName;
        }
    }
  }

  // This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it
  function findExtensions ($filename)
  {
    $filename = strtolower($filename) ;
    $extensions = explode(".", $filename) ; //$extensions = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
    $n = count($extensions)-1;
    $extensions = $extensions[$n];
    return $extensions;
  }

  // Closes $directory
  closedir($myDirectory);

  // Counts elements in array
  $indexCount = count($dirArray);
  Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n"); //Display how many files were counted

  // Sorts the Array of files
  sort($dirArray);

  // Prints the Array of files
  print("<table width='100%' cellspacing='10'>
  <tr>
    <td class='database_head'>Filename</td>
    <td class='database_head'>Filetype</td>
    <td class='database_head'>Filesize</td>
  </tr>\n");

  // Loops through the array of files and display them all
  for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
  {
    // Don't list hidden files
    if (substr($dirArray[$index], 0, 1) != ".")
    {
      print("<tr><td><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
      print("<td>");
      print(findExtensions($dirArray[$index]));
      print("</td>");
      print("<td>");
      print(filesize($directory.$dirArray[$index]));
      print("</td>");
      print("</tr>\n");
    }
  }
  print("</table>\n");
?>
```

Comment: Just before sort($dirArray) try print_r($dirArray), maybe nothing is in it. Furthermore you can instantiate the $dirArray as an array at the start $dirArray = array(); or $dirArray = [];.

By the way, your for loop can be simplified with a foreach loop ;)

Comment: If `$dirArray` is empty then it means that there isn't any valid file in the directory in the folder, right? That would mean that `$dirArray` is `null`.

Comment: Please try define variable $dirArray = array(); at the start of script or before " while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) ", it may be variable scope issue.

Comment: @Perrykipkerrie I tried using **print_r($dirArray)** infront of **sort($dirArray**, it seems to list the files fine. Could you give an example of how you would do the **foreach loop**? Nijraj and Sashant if i use **$dirArray = array();** it stops a php error from occurring, however it will still not list anything in the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
  $i=0;
  $dirArray = array();
  // Open this directory
  // (NOTE: To open same folder as this file use($directory = "./";)
  $directory = "./files/";

  // Selects $directory to open
  $myDirectory = opendir($directory);

  // Sets forbidden extensions
  $forbiddenExtensions = array("php", "html", "log");

  // Gets each entry
  while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
  {
    if (is_file($entryName))
    {
      $extensions = explode(".", $entryName);
        if(!in_array($extensions[1],$forbiddenExtensions))
        {
          $dirArray[$i++] = $entryName;
        }
    }
  }

  // This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it
  function findExtensions ($filename)
  {
    $filename = strtolower($filename) ;
    $extensions = explode(".", $filename) ; //$extensions = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
    $n = count($extensions)-1;
    $extensions = $extensions[$n];
    return $extensions;
  }

  // Closes $directory
  closedir($myDirectory);

  // Counts elements in array
  $indexCount = count($dirArray);
  Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n"); //Display how many files were counted

  // Sorts the Array of files
  sort($dirArray);

  // Prints the Array of files
  print("<table width='100%' cellspacing='10'>
  <tr>
    <td class='database_head'>Filename</td>
    <td class='database_head'>Filetype</td>
    <td class='database_head'>Filesize</td>
  </tr>\n");

  // Loops through the array of files and display them all
  for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
  {
    // Don't list hidden files
    if (substr($dirArray[$index], 0, 1) != ".")
    {
      print("<tr><td><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
      print("<td>");
      print(findExtensions($dirArray[$index]));
      print("</td>");
      print("<td>");
      print(filesize($directory.$dirArray[$index]));
      print("</td>");
      print("</tr>\n");
    }
  }
  print("</table>\n");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great example @Amur, unfortunately, when I use this I do not get any errors but the script won't list the subdirectory. The script works fine if i alter the **//Gets each entry** section to the following: `  // Gets each entry
  while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
  {
    $extensions = explode(".", $entryName);
    if(!in_array($extensions[1],$forbiddenExtensions))
      {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
      }
  }` But i want to be able to access and list sub-directories as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Burgo855 , please check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to read subdirectories .